# Is there a C++ equivalent to Javascripts Symbol()?

Tags: c++

I'm porting some code over to a C++ application and I need the functionality of a Javascript Symbol to (efficiently) generate a unique ID and store it in an std::map. Is there anything like it?

Comment: You could always just generate a UUID. It's effectively going to be unique.

Comment: I thought about that but I was wondering if there was a way that would involve less overhead, since I won't be needing a human-readable representation of the unique id: it's only needed for the program.

Comment: Just use std::hash? You might even just use the address as the unique ID.

Comment: Micronag: Porting code is usually a sucker bet because what is most efficient for Javascript may be far from efficient in C++. You want to port observable program behaviours.

Comment: If you just need something unique for the duration of the execution, wrap a class around a counter and give it suitable operations (like `operator<` for standard ordered collections). It's a dozen lines of code or so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing existing in the standard, but assuming that you do not need the full functionality of a JavaScript [Symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol), but are only interested in the unique ID part, I would recommend to use a counter.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <map>
#include <string>

template <typename T = uint64_t>
class UniqueIdGenerator
{
public:
  using type = T;
  
  auto operator()() { return next++; }
private:
  uint64_t next{0};
};

void example() {
  UniqueIdGenerator<> gen;
  auto sym1 = gen();
  auto sym2 = gen();

  std::map<UniqueIdGenerator<>::type, std::string> map = {
    {sym1, "foo"},
    {sym2, "bar"}
  };
}
```

Or an atomic counter if multiple threads will access it:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <atomic>

template <typename T = uint64_t>
class ThreadSafeUniqueIdGenerator
{
public:
  auto operator()() { return next++; }
private:
  std::atomic<T> next{0};
};
```

The generated values will be unique and if you make the integer large enough, collisions because of overflows should not be a problem. I used 64 bits here, but depending on your use case, you can also use 32 bits or even 128 bits.